# как открыть папку NotADirectoryError

Tags: python

я пытаюсь например открыть папку Program Files (x86) но прогграма вылетает

```
print("wait...")
import time
print("import time")
time.sleep(0.25)
import os
print("import os")
time.sleep(0.5)
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print("import colorama")
time.sleep(0.25)
import keyboard
print("import keyboard")
import shutil
time.sleep(0.25)
print("import shutil")
os.system('cls')

init()

line = 1
menu = 1
os.chdir("D:/")

files_dir = os.listdir()
len_files_dir = len(files_dir)

running = True
while running:
    file_dir_inx = 0
    
#    while len(files_dir) :
    while file_dir_inx < len_files_dir :# +
        element = files_dir[file_dir_inx]
        file_dir_inx = file_dir_inx + 1
        if line == file_dir_inx:
            print( Back.BLUE + Fore.WHITE + element)
        else:
            print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + element)
            
    print( Back.RESET + Fore.RESET)
    print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + os.getcwd() + files_dir[line-1])
    if menu == 1:
        print( Back.BLUE + Fore.WHITE + "|open file|" + Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + "change dir|" + Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + "delete|")
    elif menu == 2:
        print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + "|open file|" + Back.BLUE + Fore.WHITE + "change dir|" + Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + "delete|")
    if menu == 3:
        print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + "|open file|" + Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + "change dir|" + Back.BLUE + Fore.WHITE + "delete|")
    print( Back.RESET + Fore.RESET )
    key = keyboard.read_key()
    if key == "up":
        line = int(line - 1)
#-> vvvv
    elif key == "down":
        line = int(line + 1)
        if line > len_files_dir :
            line = 1

    elif key == "left":
        menu = menu-1
        if menu == 0:
            menu = 1

    elif key == "right":
        menu = menu+1
        if menu > 3:
            menu = 1
        
    elif key == "esc":
        running = False

    if menu == 2:
        if key == "enter":
            os.chdir(os.getcwd() + files_dir[line-1])
        
    os.system('cls')
```

строка: os.chdir(os.getcwd() + files_dir[line-1])

Comment: что значит "открыть папку"? В чем должно выражаться ее "открытие"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.chdir(os.getcwd() + files_dir[line-1])
```

В параметре функции `os.chdir()` отсутствует слеш (или обратный слеш) между

- текущей папкой (`os.getcwd()`) и
- именем файла (`files_dir[line-1]`).

---

*Исправление:*

Лучше всего применить вместо простого соединения строк (оператором `+`) функцию `os.path.join()`, т.е. вместо

- `os.getcwd() + files_dir[line-1]`

применить конструкцию

- `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), files_dir[line-1])`:

Функция `os.path.join()` достаточно умная — она знает, какой слеш применить и если вообще его применять (когда уже в некотором параметре существует; когда существует в обоих, она все равно использует только один).

`os.path` нужно перед применением функции `os.path.join()` где-то импортировать, значит, вместо вашей строки с ошибкой применить например
эти 2:

```
import os.path
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), files_dir[line-1]))
```